# Create UILabel dynamically and Change the text Also

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to create 7 `UILabel` programmatically and I am not able to change the text of all `UILabel`.

```
let viewsCount = 2
let viewLblcount   =   7
var messageForLbl = ["helo", "bhago", "futo", "bhensali" , "bhaaw bhaaw", "haha" ,"alladh"]

let floatValue = CGFloat(viewsCount)
let floatLbl = CGFloat(viewLblcount)

let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 30, 320, 250 * floatValue))

for i in 0 ..< viewsCount {
    let views: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 320 * CGFloat(i) + floatValue, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, 300))
    views.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    views.tag = i + 1

    for j in 0 ..< viewLblcount {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 40 * CGFloat(j) + floatLbl, self.view.frame.size.width - 100, 20))
        let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 90 * CGFloat(j) + floatLbl, self.view.frame.size.width - 100, 30))

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
        label.text = "iOS LABEL TRY"

        label2.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
        label2.text = "iOS LABEL TRY2"

        label.tag = j + 1
        label2.tag = j + 1

        views.addSubview(label)
        views.addSubview(label2)

        scrollView.addSubview(views)
        self.view!.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(310, 390 * floatValue)
    }
```

All the label is showing same text.

Comment: are you sure the labels are not overlapping each other? maybe paste a screenshot of what it looks like as well

Comment: yes its also overlapping each other i m not sure how to fix this problem

Comment: i think you should change the way you are calculating the frames positions, maybe keep an array of all the previously created labels, then when you are making the next labels, you can reference the previous one and position this new one relative to its frame, and not calculated from scratch each iteration

Comment: i will fixed this issue letter bcz my problem is that i am not able to change label text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the text of the labels hardcoded on these lines:

```
label.text = "iOS LABEL TRY"
label2.text = "iOS LABEL TRY2"
```

I'm not exactly sure what text you want in each label, but I think you want to change it to:

```
label.text = messageForLbl[j]
```

Also, you can avoid a future bug by using Swift's enumerators (then you don't have to change `viewLblcount` when you change `messageForLbl`):

```
for value in messageForLbl.enumerate() {
    label.text = value
}
```

Comment: Cool!  If it's working out, you might flag this as answered.

Comment: That's exactly it.  Sometimes people like me are browsing around looking for unanswered questions to help out.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Because you have hard coded the text

label.text = "iOS LABEL TRY"

Comment: Then what should i use?

Comment: You can use it  label.text = label2.text = messageForLbl[j];